# centOS install mysqlclient fail (via pip3)

Tags: django, python-3.x, centos

I am trying to run Django2.0 on centOS server, 
I have installed python3 and pip3,
django2.0 also installed under virtualenv,
but an error pop out when I tried to install mysqlclient under virturlenv, error msg below:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-7hd8p93o/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-7hd8p93o/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-7hd8p93o/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7hd8p93o/mysqlclient/
```

Any idea please

Answer (score 7):

I solved the same issue with:

```
sudo yum install python36u-devel mysql-devel
```

Comment: On centos 7.4 I solved with `sudo yum install python3-devel`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue with!

```
yum install -y python3-devel.x86_64
```